# Правильное использование Аксессоров

Tags: c#

Хочу обратиться к данному элементу через другой класс:

```
public static string WinDir = (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"));
```

Из видео-уроков по c# я понял что это не правильно.

---

Как лучше использовать свойства?

Так:

```
public static string WinDir {get;set;} = (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"));
```

Или так:

```
public static string WinDir {get;private set;} = (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"));
```

---

Меня интересуют последние 2 способа:

`{get;set;}` - Его же можно изменять из другого класса правильно?

А `{get;private set;}` - изменять нельзя, он только получит путь?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну во-первых, мало толку от создания статической обертки над статическим методом из стандартной библиотеки, почему бы не использовать сразу `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir")` там где он нужен.

Во-вторых, (уж не знаю какая вероятность у этого, но) результат этого метода может меняться от вызова к вызову, поэтому не очень хорошо сохранять его и всегда использовать сохраненное значение, поэтому, опуская предыдущий абзац лучше уж написать что-то вроде:

```
public static string WinDir { get { return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"); } }
```

или, в новых версиях языка, можно сократить до выражения:

```
public static string WinDir => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
```

Ну и, если не учитывать все вышеизложенное, у вас есть несколько путей:

Если функционал свойства не нужен (а в некоторых случаях от них нельзя уйти), то можно сделать readonly-поле:

```
public static readonly string WinDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
```

В новых версиях языка также появилась возможность создания свойств только для чтения без явного использования backing-field:

```
public static string WinDir { get; } = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
```

Что касается ваших вопросов:

`{ get; set; }` - да, это свойство может быть изменено снаружи и это вам, скорее всего, не нужно.

`{ get; private set; }` - это свойство может быть изменено только в коде этого класса, это уже лучше, но все равно вероятность ошибки есть.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, надеюсь понятно расписал